# how to interact with MS Word content controls using PHP?

Tags: php, ms-word, phpword

I have been tasked to create a document control system written in PHP which utilises existing word templates.
The templates have content controls which I must populate from MySQL database.

I am struggling to find a method to modify the values of the MS Word content controls on the server side.
I have read the documentation for PHPWord, and spent hours searching the web.

Has anyone managed to do this using PHP?

Comment: What do you mean by "content controls"?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/working-with-word/working-with-content-controls

Comment: A similar request (in 2018 already) has been raised to add content controls interaction thru PHPWord. Unfortunately it seems that no milestone is set yet (and no developer has been assigned to work on it).  Please see [this link](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/1520) for details.

Comment: Thanks Ken, I thought as much, but was wondering if anyone had manged to do it another way?